# How to SUM values of a column and then order by another column using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, mariadb, sql-order-by

When I `SELECT * FROM table;` I have the following result:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+-------+
| state | number | candidate   | votes |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------+
| AR    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |     9 |
| AR    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |    23 |
| LA    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |    19 |
| OK    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |     2 |
| TX    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |     7 |
| TX    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |     7 |
| AR    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |     2 |
| LA    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |     5 |
| LA    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |     1 |
| OK    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |    17 |
| OK    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |    21 |
| TX    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |     7 |
| LA    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |    14 |
| LA    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |    42 |
| OK    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |    13 |
| OK    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |     5 |
| TX    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |     1 |
| TX    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |     4 |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

So I try to sum the total of votes with `SUM(votes) as tt_votes` and then group the result by candidate to have a desc order.

```
SELECT state, number, name, SUM(votes) as tt_votes 
FROM table 
GROUP BY candidate 
ORDER BY tt_votes DESC;

+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
| state | number | candidate   | tt_votes |
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
| LA    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |       79 |
| AR    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |       67 |
| TX    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |       53 |
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

`state` column shows the first (or the last?) record for the candidate, but what I'd really like to have is not only group by candidates, but also group by state first to have a result like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
| state | number | candidate   | tt_votes |
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
| AR    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |       32 |
| AR    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |        2 |
| AR    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |        0 |
| LA    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |       56 |
| LA    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |       19 |
| LA    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |        6 |
| OK    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |       38 |
| OK    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |       18 |
| OK    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |        2 |
| TX    |     12 | CANDIDATE A |       14 |
| TX    |     25 | CANDIDATE B |        7 |
| TX    |     17 | CANDIDATE C |        5 |
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

It lists the states in alphabetic order and then the tt_votes of each candidate in each state order by tt_votes.

Tried UNION or inserting `WHERE state = AR` for example, but without success.
Any ideas how it could be done?

**EDIT**

If I use (SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'AR' GROUP BY state, number, candidate) UNION ((SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'LA' GROUP BY state, number, candidate) UNION (SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'OK' GROUP BY state, number, candidate); etc. I have what we need. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just use `GROUP state,number,candidate ORDER BY state, tt_votes DESC` if I understand correctly what you need

Comment: how did you arrive at `tt_votes` as `31`,`2` and `0` for `state` is `AR`. what is this logic

Comment: Your first query is invalid. That you don't get a syntax error indicates that you have not `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` and thus are working in the notorious cheating mode that MySQL unfortunately offers. Yes, state and number are completely arbitrary in the result; MySQL picks them from any rows of the candidate. (It silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on these columns behind the scenes.) Is `name` a typo for `candidate` or is this yet another column?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not decribed the task well. It seems you want one result row per candidate and state and these rows shall show the vote sums and one of the numbers, you dn't care which (well, in your sample data they are all the same per candidate anyway). Is this the case? The results you are showing say no, because for CANDIDATE A / AR you should get number 12 and sum 32, but in your results it is number 17 and sum 31. Typos or some logic I have failed to understand?

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner candidate A is always 12, B is always 25 and C always 17. It was a typo, sorry. I've just edited this.

Comment: Okay, then you have a table that violates database normalization. You should better have a separate table with one row per candidate holding that number. Then you can use GSM's query and change `SELECT state, number, name, SUM(votes) as tt_votes` to `SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes`.

Comment: @MoulitharanM it was a typo. The right is 32, 2, 0 (the sum of votes for each candidate in that state).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If I use (SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'AR' GROUP BY state, number, candidate) UNION ((SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'LA' GROUP BY state, number, candidate) UNION (SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) as tt_votes WHERE state = 'OK' GROUP BY state, number, candidate); etc. I have what we need. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. `UNION` is not appropriate here, you'd want `UNION ALL`, because there are no duplicates to remove. Then you can remove "number" from `GROUP BY`, because you use an aggregation function `ANY_VALUE`) on it. And if you want to restrict this to AR, LA and OK, then simply use `WHERE state IN ('AR', 'LA', 'OK')`, and you are done. No need for multiple queries the results of which you glue together with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT state, ANY_VALUE(number), candidate, SUM(votes) AS tt_votes   
FROM table   
GROUP BY state, candidate     
ORDER BY state, candidate;
```

Comment: This query is still invalid - which number do you want to pick? It also makes no sense to include the votes in `ORDER BY`, because there is only one result row per state and candidate in the results. And you have copied the select list from OP's query, where "name" is probably a typo for "candidate".

Comment: good catch @ThorstenKettner, I did change OP's query, will edit that now

Comment: I've edited the query and applied `ANY_VALUE` on "number", so as to make this a valid query without syntax errors. The answer would have been better by the way, did you explain what the query does and how it solves the task. Don't post code-only answers.